# Full Page Livewire is not allowing page access after close of a modal

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

So I'm working on creating a full page livewire route, the route is working and the page loads correctly. On my page I have a livewire component that allows Jetstream modal-dialog to open a form. This is great and the associated forms open as expected and can be clicked outside to close or the close button clicked.

However after doing this I cannot do anything on my page. The pointer doesn;t change and I am unable to do anything with the page until i reload the page. Obviously thats not desirable and defeats the whole point of using livewire for the page. My add component actually opens one of 6 modals on the page so perhaps this can be refactored? on my standard non livewire pages this issue does not happen!

The code is lengthy and for brevity I will show the AddButton component and the ManageClientModal component although the other modals work in the same way.

AddButton.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Tools;

use Livewire\Component;

class AddButton extends Component
{
    public bool $showUser     = false;
    public bool $showClient   = false;
    public bool $showMerchant = false;
    public bool $showJob      = false;
    public bool $showHoliday  = false;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->showUser     = auth()->user()->can( 'manage users' );
        $this->showClient   = auth()->user()->can( 'manage clients' );
        $this->showMerchant = auth()->user()->can( 'manage merchants' );
        $this->showJob      = auth()->user()->can( 'manage jobs' );
        $this->showHoliday  = true;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tools.add-button');
    }

    public function showUserModal( $user_id, $delete )
    {
        $this->emit('showUserModal', $user_id, $delete);
    }

    public function showClientModal( $client_id, $delete )
    {
        $this->emit('showClientModal', $client_id, $delete);
    }

    public function showMerchantModal( $merchant_id, $delete )
    {
        $this->emit('showMerchantModal', $merchant_id, $delete);
    }

    public function showJobModal( $job_number, $delete )
    {
        $this->emit('showJobModal', $job_number, $delete);
    }

    public function showHolidayModal( $holiday_id, $delete )
    {
        $this->emit('showHolidayModal', auth()->id(), $holiday_id, $delete);
    }

}
```

and add-button.blade.php:

```
<div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }" @click.away="open = false" @close.stop="open = false">
    <div @click="open = ! open">
        <div class="hidden space-x-8 md:-my-px md:ml-10 lg:flex">
            <button type="button" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-blue-400 py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded">
                {!! config( 'ecl.ADD_SUCCESS' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add' ) }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-200" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute z-50 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg origin-top-right right-0 " style="display: none;" @click="open = false">
        <div class="rounded-md ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 py-1  bg-white">
            <!-- Account Management -->
            <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                Add Actions
            </div>
            @if( $showJob )
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition" wire:click="showJobModal(0, 0)">{!! config( 'ecl.JOBS' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add A Job' ) }}</a>
            @endif
            @if( $showClient )
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition" wire:click="showClientModal(0, 0)">{!! config( 'ecl.CLIENTS' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add A Client' ) }}</a>
            @endif
            @if( $showMerchant )
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition" wire:click="showMerchantModal(0, 0)">{!! config( 'ecl.MERCHANTS' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add A Merchant' ) }}</a>
            @endif
            @if( $showUser )
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition" wire:click="showUserModal(0, 0)">{!! config( 'ecl.USERS' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add A User' ) }}</a>
            @endif
            @if( $showHoliday )
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition" wire:click="showHolidayModal(0, 0)">{!! config( 'ecl.PLANE' ) !!} {{ __( 'Add A Holiday' ) }}</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    @livewire('modals.manage-job', ['showButton' => false])
    @livewire('modals.manage-client', ['showButton' => false])
    @livewire('modals.manage-merchant', ['showButton' => false])
    @livewire('modals.manage-user', ['showButton' => false])
    @livewire('modals.add-holiday', ['showButton' => false])
</div>
```

my ManageClient.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Modals;

use App\Models\Client;
use Livewire\Component;

class ManageClient extends Component
{
    public bool   $showingModal = false;
    public bool   $showButton = true;
    public int    $delete = 0;
    public string $header;

    protected $listeners =[
        'refresh' => '$refresh',
        'showClientModal' => 'showClientModal'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.modals.manage-client');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        if ( $this->delete === 0 ) {

            $this->adder = false;
        } else {
            //$this->adder = $this->adder;
        }

        $this->hideModal();
    }

    public function showClientModal( $clientId, $delete )
    {
        $this->delete = $delete;
        $this->client_id = $clientId;
        if ( $clientId > 0 ) {
            $client = Client::find( $clientId );
            $this->header         = 'Edit the Client';
            $this->adder          = false;
        } else {
            $this->header         = 'Add a Client';
            $this->adder          = true;
        }
        if ( $delete ) {
            $this->header = 'Delete this Client';
        }
        $this->showingModal = true;
    }

    public function hideModal()
    {
        $this->showingModal = false;
    }
}
```

and the manage-client.blade.php:

```
<span>
     @if($showButton)

    @endif
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit()">
        <x-dialog-modal wire:model="showingModal" maxWidth="2xl" class="flex items-center">

            <x-slot name="title">
                {{ $header }}
            </x-slot>


            <x-slot name="content">
                @if( $delete === 0 )
                    <div class="md:col-span-1 flex justify-between">
                        <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                            <h3 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">Client Information</h3>

                            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                                Please complete the fields to manage the Client.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <p>Click Yes if you would like to remove the following client or No to leave it alone:</p>
                    <p class="bg-gray-200 dark:!bg-gray-800">{{ $title }}</p>
                    <p> A deleted comment cannot be restored!</p>
                    <br><hr>
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this comment?</p>
                @endif
            </x-slot>

            <x-slot name="footer">
                @if ( $delete === 0 )
                    <x-button class="mx-2" type="submit">
                        {{ __('Submit') }}
                    </x-button>

                    <x-secondary-button wire:click="$set('showingModal', false)" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                        {{ __('Cancel')  }}
                    </x-secondary-button>
                @else
                    <x-button class="mx-2" type="submit">
                        {{ __('Yes') }}
                    </x-button>

                    <x-secondary-button wire:click="$set('showingModal', false)" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                        {{ __('No')  }}
                    </x-secondary-button>
                @endif
            </x-slot>

        </x-dialog-modal>
    </form>
</span>
```

Just to reiterate, the issue is not with the route as the page loads and works as expected until a modal is opened and then closed. Even submitting does this and seems to leave a transparent overlay over the whole page! I have considered that maybe some refresh from the AddButton would fix this and have tried using javascript but the only way to get access to the page after handling any Modal is to reload the page!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't really hide your modal, you just remove the show class in the modal. I think you need to emit an hideModal event.

```
public function hideModal()
{
   $this->showingModal = false;
   $this->emit('hideModal', 'your-modal-id');
}
```

Then, in your parent component, you add a javascript:

```
<script>
    Livewire.on('hideModal',(modalId)=>{
       $('#' + modalId).modal('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This helped but ulimately made no difference. I ended up dropping it as being a full page livewire component and everything works. Probably come back to this but got plenty of other things to do on this project and as this has taken 2 days it is time to move on...